# Using conditional statement (CASE) within a WHERE statement in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a TextBox and two DropDownLists, used in a search function. The two DropDownLists take their values from columns in the 'Products' table in my DB ('Product_Rental' and 'Range_Name'). They can be used in conjunction with one another so if Range_Name is selected, you can still select the Product_Rental (rental price range) DropDownList to further narrow your search. These will be passed via a QueryString to a separate page with a GridView displaying the results.

My question is, what is the best way of doing this in a SQL statement? I'm assuming I need some sort of conditional statement which, for example, only uses the 'Product_Rental' query if there are results are found for the 'Range_Name' query.

After doing some digging, it looks like I need to use the CASE statement, but I'm unsure how.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    SELECT  Product_Rental, Product_ID, Range_Name, Model_Name, Product_Name, Product_Year, Product_Code, Product_Active, Product_DateAdded
    FROM    Products
    WHERE   (Range_Name LIKE '%' + @Range_Name + '%') OR
            (Model_Name LIKE '%' + @Model_Name + '%') OR
            (Product_Name LIKE '%' + @Product_Name + '%') OR
            (Product_Code LIKE '%' + @Product_Code + '%') OR
            (Product_Year LIKE '%' + @Product_Year + '%') OR
            (CONVERT(float, Product_Rental) BETWEEN CONVERT(float, @Product_Rental) AND CONVERT(float, @Product_Rental) + 50)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the default value of the variables is the empty string, then you can just change the `or` to `and` (and fix up the floating point comparison):

```
SELECT  Product_Rental, Product_ID, Range_Name, Model_Name, Product_Name, Product_Year, Product_Code, Product_Active, Product_DateAdded
FROM    Products
WHERE   (Range_Name LIKE '%' + @Range_Name + '%') AND
        (Model_Name LIKE '%' + @Model_Name + '%') AND
        (Product_Name LIKE '%' + @Product_Name + '%') AND
        (Product_Code LIKE '%' + @Product_Code + '%') AND
        (Product_Year LIKE '%' + @Product_Year + '%') AND
        ((CONVERT(float, Product_Rental) BETWEEN CONVERT(float, @Product_Rental) AND CONVERT(float, @Product_Rental) + 50) or @Product_Rental = '')
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I tried that and it didn't seem to do the trick. Maybe I need to explain more. So, the way I have it set up, my search function will return a URL - 'SearchResults.aspx?range=A3' (if 'Range_Name' only is selected) and something like 'SearchResults.aspx?range=A3&price=200' when both of the drop down lists are selected. Using my SQL query, the they work individually, but not together.

Answer (score 0):

So I will be under the assumption that you will be "cleaning" your inbound parameters and under control of them before actually submitting the @values to your sql query.  That said, always make available all the criteria of their respective data type expectations... string, integer, date, whatever.

Then, in your query, apply an OR as needed.

From scenario 1 where only a range is provided and no other model, name, year, etc

```
@Range = "something" (however comes in from .aspx)
@model = "-"
@name = "-"
@year = -1
etc..
```

Now the WHERE Clause

```
where
       Range_Name LIKE '%' + @Range + '%') 
   AND (@model = "-" OR Model_Name like '%' + @model + '%') 
   AND (@name = "-" OR Product_Name LIKE '%' + @name + '%') 
   AND (@year = -1 OR Product_Year = @year )
```

So, think of how it will get processed... Always qualify the range based on the like qualifier.  Then, for each of the other OPTIONAL criteria, I've defaulted them to some "user didnt enter a value for"... I used - and -1 respectively.

Now, when the AND is applied for those OPTIONAL ones, since each OPTIONAL is in its own (parens with an OR condition), if the first part is true, it considers it as ok and ignores the second part of the condition.

So when @model is defaulted to "-", the AND says... if model = "-", yup, we're good, ignore the rest of the LIKE comparison of this paren group.  Likewise for the rest.

Now, you get another query with the range and a YEAR value, for example).  The only real value you need to assign is the @year to say... 2013.  Then THAT part of the where clause is assessed as

```
AND ( @year = -1 OR Product_Year = @year )
```

The @year = -1 fails, so it then falls through and checks for the product_year = 2013 and that confirms if it qualifies the criteria or not.

This way, you can prebuild all your criteria into the WHERE and as each individually MAY be passed, it will either be tested for or bypassed (via the left-side OR qualifier) allows the row returned.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful post. I tried your approach and have come across some problems. Can I ask ... in your top code block, is that a select statement? If so, would I have to declare those first?

Comment: @hewsy10, the top code block of the (at)variables I would suspect YOU were preparing anyhow, somewhere along the cleansing of incoming asp.net request.  Those would be the parameter values you have when calling your actual SQL statement.  I was just updating how the WHERE clause would look based on values supplied (or not).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
Use Northwind
GO


declare @ProductNameLikeFilter varchar(64)
declare @QuantityPerUnitLikeFilter varchar(64)


select @ProductNameLikeFilter = 'ge'
select @QuantityPerUnitLikeFilter = 'g'
select 
 *
from
    dbo.[Products] prods
where
( @ProductNameLikeFilter IS NULL OR prods.ProductName like '%' + @ProductNameLikeFilter + '%' )
and
( @QuantityPerUnitLikeFilter IS NULL OR prods.QuantityPerUnit like '%' + @QuantityPerUnitLikeFilter + '%' )


select @ProductNameLikeFilter = NULL
select @QuantityPerUnitLikeFilter = NULL

select 
 *
from
    dbo.[Products] prods
where
( @ProductNameLikeFilter IS NULL OR prods.ProductName like '%' + @ProductNameLikeFilter + '%' )
and
( @QuantityPerUnitLikeFilter IS NULL OR prods.QuantityPerUnit like '%' + @QuantityPerUnitLikeFilter + '%' )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I am using a .xsd DataTableAdapter to generate the SQL query and I keep getting an error that the DECLARE statement is not supported. Is that down to my SQL server? It looks like I'm on SQL 2005.

Comment: I didn't realize you were using inline sql.  No, declare statements are for stored procedures.  This answer will not help you.